# Widgets jump at the bottom of the page in wordpress template

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, widget

I dont know what I have done wrong. I have couple of widgets displayed in my home page. two of them are my cystom widgets. I would like them to display in the right column of my page. I dont know why some of them jump at the bottom of my page. (I am using bootstrap but I have extended the grid system to 24 columns)
[image]

```
I display them like that:

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-18">
             //some code here    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could someone help ?

Comment: i think there is div in the sidebar widget which is not closed properly and breaking the html, you need to check your widget

Comment: As Balwant has said, this looks like it's caused by a HTML element not being closed properly. Can you post the HTML you have used in your 'about' widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one or more unclosed `<div>`'s, meaning you are missing one or two `</div>` closing tags.

The best thing to do is use the html validator at https://validator.w3.org to find them. Enter your URL (for a public site) or use the "Validate by direct input" to cut/paste browser source. Check the errors and you will find the unclosed divs.

If your code is in plain text or html widgets, it should be easier to find the divs. But the `divs` may also be in generated html source, so you may have to carefully look into the `php` in theme templates to find where they are output.

You will get lots of information and code warnings with the validator; many warnings are just technical in nature and you can safely ignore them.

Comment: Ok I know now ! 

I had the line    `<?php echo $args['after_widget'];` in my widget file. I shlould use GIT... 

Thank you for all anwers !